# getting json from file inside project going to error

Tags: ajax, json, getjson

```
$.getJSON("images/carouselPhotos.json", function(data) {
                console.log(data);


            });
```

This is how my json code looks like and my json file looks as follows

```
{photos : 
[{photo : https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/480658_569309203089775_1014136234_n.jpg},
{photo : https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/422022_569309163089779_1265521956_n.jpg},
{photo : https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/270818_569309029756459_1227033818_n.jpg},
{photo : https://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/575588_569308903089805_682444353_n.jpg},
{photo : https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/524702_569308839756478_866096962_n.jpg},
{photo : https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/420761_569308689756493_1009837829_n.jpg}]
}
```

I dont see anything wrong anywhere but this call to the json file ends up in the error function. I am able to see the JSON data in error.responseText. Why is that? Can someone let me know what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Nikhil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON syntax dictates that keys ans strings must be quoted with `"`, so your data as json would be

```
{
    "photos": [
        {
            "photo": "https: //fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/480658_569309203089775_1014136234_n.jpg"
        },
        {
            "photo": "https: //fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/422022_569309163089779_1265521956_n.jpg"
        },
        {
            "photo": "https: //fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/270818_569309029756459_1227033818_n.jpg"
        },
        {
            "photo": "https: //sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/575588_569308903089805_682444353_n.jpg"
        },
        {
            "photo": "https: //fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/524702_569308839756478_866096962_n.jpg"
        },
        {
            "photo": "https: //fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/420761_569308689756493_1009837829_n.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

though your urls would be wrong since the have a space in them

also see http://json.org

Comment: Thanks very much. Guess I got too caught up in the other details that I stopped seeing the obvious stuff :D